# How to make an excel sheet dynamically reference another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to make an excel sheet that generates material costs for construction. My plan is to have one sheet where I can enter the material and its quantity, and another that stores the prices of materials. That way, in the future when material costs change, I only need edit one sheet instead of every instance of the same material.

How would I make it so that (for example) imputing the material into x1 on Sheet A pulls the price from y2 Sheet B and puts it in to z2 on Sheet A?

Comment: Sounds like Vlookup, Index/Match, or Xlookup will do what you want.

Comment: Could you provide a sample here?

Comment: Further to Scott’s answer, the formula will be entered into your *results* sheet, and will *lookup* the material in cost sheet.  So if your material is entered into A1, then the formula in B1 of the result sheet is something like `=VLOOKUP( A1, CostSheet!$A$2:$B$100), 2)`.